# MYSQL - after update check whether value is not negative if yes throw error

Tags: mysql, sql-update

HOW to create SQL statement that UPDATE record in the table and after updated check whether

value is not negative if yes, throw ERROR!

---

Since I use TRANSACTION (ROLLBACK,COMMIT) I will use it to define whether should

I commit or rollback.

---

Thank in advance.

Comment: Normally, you would want to do this *before* the update or insert to prevent the value from going in.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a trigger that checks the value after each insert. It will fire an error if the column `value` is less than zero.

```
delimiter |
CREATE TRIGGER `check_value` AFTER UPDATE ON your_table 
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    IF NEW.value < 0 THEN
      SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'value can not be negative';
   END IF
END
|
delimiter ;
```